# How to replace two first characters before underscore with regex?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have example this string:

```
HU_husnummer
HU_Adrs
```

How can I replace `HU`? with `MI`?

So it will be `MI_husnummer` and `MI_Adrs`.

I am not very good at regex but I would like to solve it with regex.

**EDIT**:

The sample code I have now and that still does not work is:

```
string test = Regex.Replace("[HU_husnummer] int NOT NULL","^HU","MI");
```

Comment: Your string always has _only_ one `HU`? Or replace before the `_` character?

Comment: So `"HU_husnummer".Replace("HU_", "MI_")` is not sufficient?

Comment: Then start reading a regex tutorial and try something before asking for a complete solution.

Comment: I tried else i wont be posting.

Comment: I like the fact, that somebody is downvoting this after 3 years. Dont you have anything better to do than going through my questions and downvoting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your comments, you actually need

```
string test = Regex.Replace("[HU_husnummer] int NOT NULL",@"^\[HU","[MI");
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://ideone.com/dIdmcP)

In case your input string really starts with `HU`, remove the `\[` from the regex pattern.

The regex is `@"^\[HU"` (note the verbatim string literal notation used for regex pattern):

- `^` - matches the start of string
- `\[` - matches a literal `[` (since it is a special regex metacharacter denoting a beginning of a character class)
- `HU` - matches `HU` literally.

Comment: @user3436271: Please do not add answers providing feedback, add comments, either to your question, or the others' answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
String varString="HU_husnummer ";
varString=varString.Replace("HU_","MI_");
```

**Links**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace

Answer (score 0):

using Substring

```
var abc = "HU_husnummer";
var result = "MI" + abc.Substring(2);
```

Replace in Regex.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(abc, "^HU", "MI");
```